# Can't Save Image Attributes with Paperclip in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, strong-parameters

I have two associated models in my Rails 4 app: `product.rb` and `image.rb`. The Image model allows attached files using the Paperclip gem.

Images `belong_to` a Product, and a product `has_many` Images.

I would like to use the Product's `new` view to create and attach an image when I create a product. Each time I try, the parameters associated with the Paperclip image do not get saved, and end up `nil`.

Here are the models:

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :part_number, presence: true
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

Looking through past Stack Overflow questions I've found some relevant questions and answers, but none that seem to help my particular situation. So far I'm able to submit the file with the correct attributes, but it doesn't save them to the database.

**`ProductsController#create`**

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name,
                                  :category_id,
                                  :part_number,
                                  images_attributes: [:image])
end
```

**`ProductsController#new`**

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @categories = # irrelevant to question
end
```

**`products/new.html.haml`**

```
= form_for @product, :html => 
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.label :part_number
  = f.text_field :part_number
  = f.label :category_id
  = f.select :category_id, @ca
  = f.fields_for :image do |ff|
    = ff.label :image 
    = ff.file_field :image
  = f.submit('Create Product')
```

Looking at the parameters I can tell that the correct attributes are being passed on:

**Example parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"jGNy/TasHzP0EcWDFzZ3XH5/fpxb6vD+ncQ2PZSQ3/I=",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"bar",
 "part_number"=>"foo",
 "category_id"=>"30",
 "image"=>{
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc82f58e0e0
 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/04/23d9grkj5fv3wkj2t8858kx40000gn/T/RackMultipart20131029-64949-1ldkz4g>,
 @original_filename="FPE230_b.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image][image]\"; filename=\"FPE230_b.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}},
 "commit"=>"Create Product"}
```

However, the image is not actually being saved to the database. How can I rectify this?

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at the logs, I see that I'm getting an "unpermitted parameters: image" error. This is even after adding `images_attributes: [:image]` to my `product_params` method.

Comment: What version of paperclip are you using, please?

Comment: The latest: `gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"`

Comment: For future reference, the commit at the HEAD of github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip today is 8e900b2a139deff9114efe84e6327235c92e6103. Could you confirm that's the commit you're using? It was just updated 2 days ago and changes fairly frequently. Thanks!

Comment: Good point. I was behind HEAD by a commit or two. While diagnosing the issue I'll use 3.5.2 for the sake of stability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get a setup similar to yours working with the following changes:

In `ProductsController#create`, instead of building the image separately, let the nested attributes handle it and just do:

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

And allow the nested parameters (I figured out the `image_attributes: [:image]` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370946/unpermitted-parameters-on-multiple-paperclip-file-uploads-rails4)):

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :part_number, images_attributes: [:image])
end
```

This is what my parameters look like in the logs for a `create` request:

```
{
   "utf8"=>"✓", 
   "authenticity_token"=>"7EsPTNXu127itgp4fbohu672/L4XnSwLEkrqUGec3pY=", 
   "product"=>{
     "name"=>"whatever", 
     "part_number"=>"12345", 
     "images_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{
         "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feb0c183b08 
           @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/6k/16k80dds0ddd6mhvs5zryh3r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131031-51205-emaijs>, 
           @original_filename="some-image.png", 
           @content_type="image/png", 
           @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"ponysay.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">
        }
      }
    }, 
    "commit"=>"Create"}
```

And I see an insert into `products` and an insert into `images`.

If that doesn't work, could you post your `ProductsController#new` and your new product form?

EDIT AFTER YOUR EDIT:

I have 3 different things in my `app/views/products/new.html.erb` and `ProductsController#new` that might be affecting your results:

1. In the `form_for`, I have `multipart: true` as in the [paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start):

   ```
   <%= form_for @product, :url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   ```
2. Because `Product` `has_many :images`, in my form I have `fields_for :images` instead of `fields_for :image`:

   ```
   <%= f.fields_for :images do |i| %>
     <%= i.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
   ```
3. This `fields_for` doesn't show anything on the page unless in the `ProductsController#new` I build an image; does your `Product.new` do this by any chance?

   ```
   def new
     @product = Product.new
     @product.images.build
   end
   ```

Are there any particular reasons for these differences you have? Does your code work if you change it to match mine?

Comment: Still not working. I've added the `new` method and the form, at the risk of scaring off everyone with a wall of text for a question.

Comment: Sometimes a wall of text is what's needed :)

Comment: It was the plural `images` in `fields_for`! Thanks!