# uploading files to rails 4.0 with paperclip and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Edit:** as @Justin said, I probably messed that up when trying to find a solution without even realizing, oopsy... Changing the params to params.require(:pin).permit(:image, :description) did solve it.
Though it doesn't work now because I get a "has an extension that does not match its contents.

I'm following Rails One Month and trying to get upload image into a pins scaffolding working.
I'm using paperclip for files, and simple_form. This is the code I think is relevant (feel free to ask for anything):

**_pin_form.erb.html**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@pin, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

 <div class="form-inputs">
   <%= f.file_field :image, :label => "Upload an image" %>
   <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
```

**pin.rb**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_attached_file :image
 belongs_to :user

 validates :description, :presence => true
 validates :user_id, :presence => true
 validates_attachment :image, :presence => true

# Validate content type
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage/
# Validate filename
 validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
# Explicitly do not validate
 do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end
```

**pin_params from pins_controller.rb**

```
def pin_params
  params.permit(:description, :image)
end
```

(most of these is when I tried troubleshooting through paperclip README).
Whenever I upload a file I get an error saying

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PinsController#create
param not found: image
```

and if I try to use params.require on something I get an error saying param not found.
I have no idea what is causing it. If I remove the pin_params method the form fields just return "can't be blank" no matter what's in them"
This seems simple but I just can't find a solution to this

Comment: You get an error using `params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)`? Also with simple_form, you can just specify `f.input :image, label: "Upload an image"`

Comment: You should figure out with strong parameters, cause i guess image not just one attribute, it's an array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664744/cant-save-image-attributes-with-paperclip-in-rails-4

Comment: Could you show the parameters coming into your controller from the view please.

Comment: Log params and check that they present. `Rails.logger.debug params`

Comment: @Zishe, if he properly set up his migration on his `pins` table for paperclip, he shouldn't have to specify that in his params.

Comment: I think that the change @Justin gave did solve the problem. I probably messed that up when trying to find a solution without even realizing, oopsy... Though it doesn't work now because I get a "has an extension that does not match its contents" error on the picture. As a side note, I'm not using f.input since I wasn't able to make it look ok with bootstrap 3 ><

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I would if I knew how :P

Comment: Your model has 3 validators for `image`.  Normally you should just have one of these - either validate the content type, the file type or state you don't want to do any validation.  Your new error is coming from the content type validator - what is your operating system?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean windows 7 64-bit. And removign all but the content type didn't change anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paperclip has spoofing validation to ensure the contents of the file actually match the extension.  This validation is achieved partially by using the `file` command of the operating system to determine the file content.  Unfortunately Windows doesn't have a `file` command so the validation will always fail.

To workaround this you should disable spoofing.  Create an initializer with the following code:

```
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

It's valid to leave the `validates_attachment_content_type` validator though because is it still the best way to restrict the types of files the user is allowed to upload.  You just need to disable the spoofing bit of this validation.

Comment: Ahh I see. I noticed the file command part in the paperclip README but didn't realize it was connected. Thank you very much (and @justin) for your help :)

Comment: Although this works, it will be a workaround - how is your system spoofing the files to check their type?

Comment: @RichPeck I use ubuntu, not Windows.  Even so I had to hack `MediaTypeSpoofDetector` a little as `file --mime-type` does not always work; so if that fails I use `mimetype` instead.  I agree with what the spoofing detector in Paperclip is trying to do, but it does seem to be causing a lot of problems in its implementation.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Graeme. Sure - it causes mannnnny problems - good to see someone who knows how to fix :)